# Deviation of random matrix from its expectation informs the positiveness of its second smallest eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, random-matrices

Let $A$ be a PSD random matrix, which has $0$ as one of its eigenvalues. The second smallest eigenvalue of the expectation of $A$ writes as $\lambda_2(\mathbb{E}(A))>0$.

Why the following statement holds?

If $\|A-\mathbb{E}(A)\|<\lambda_2(\mathbb{E}(A))$, then $\lambda_2(A)>0.$

Note that $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the operator norm.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I want to prove $\lambda_2(A)>0$ instead of $\lambda_2(\mathbb{E}(A))>0$

Comment: clear, thank you for the clarifying edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random-matrix connection is a bit of a red herring: Since the weight of $A$ in the statistical average can be arbitrarily small, we might as well replace $\mathbb{E}(A)$ by an arbitrary PSD matrix $B$ with $\lambda_2(B)>0$.
The statement in the OP

> If $\|A-B\|<\lambda_2(B)$, then $\lambda_2(A)>0,$

is a consequence of the "eigenvalue stability" inequality
$$|\lambda_i(A)-\lambda_i(B)|\leq \|A-B\|,$$
which is proven, for example, in [Tao's notes](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/254a-notes-3a-eigenvalues-and-sums-of-hermitian-matrices/) (equation 13).

Comment: Hi @Carlo Beenakker. I don't understand what does this mean "Since the weight of  in the statistical average can be arbitrarily small, we might as well replace $\mathbb{E}(A)$ by an arbitrary PSD matrix $B$ with $\lambda_2(B)>0$." Could you clarify more on it? 

I understand the answer based on: if $B$ is PSD and $\lambda_2(B)>0$, $\|A-B\|<\lambda_2(B)$, then $\lambda_2(A)>0$.

Comment: it just means your statement about $\lambda_2(A)>0$ holds if $\|A-B\|<\lambda_2(B)$ for _any_ PSD $B$; the fact that $A$ is random and $B=\mathbb{E}[A]$ is irrelevant, it does not constrain $B$ in any way.

Comment: I see. Thank you!